# Why might "eu" be pronounced like "ai"?

Tags: prononciation

I was listening to the song *Secret* by Louane and I keep getting hung up on how she pronounces one word in the chorus. You can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY6-BbXcoGY&ab_channel=Frenchielyrics) at 1:09, when she sings "J'ai toujours eu un peu de mal à m'aimer" but she pronounces the *eu* as *ai*, almost as though she were saying *J'ai toujours ai*. She does it again in every chorus of the song. You can hear it mostly clearly in the song's final line, at 3:00, when she says it a bit more slowly, but again pronounces it the same way.

Why is that? I haven't heard it pronounced that way before. Does this somehow sound normal to a native speaker's ears anyway?

Comment: I really don't hear what you're hearing. To me it's a very clear /y/. Maybe you're picking up some kind of diphthongization with the nasal vowel after it. Or anticipating a rhyme because of the internal rhymes 'confier' / 'secret' / ___ / 'aimer'.

Comment: It is "u" in all cases, clearly so; it seems strange though that your ear should need more training to make this difference.

Comment: Indeed. The result of learning a language from books. Bad ears. 12 years later it remains a struggle. But it's all I focus on these days. Hope springs eternal.

Comment: @temporary_user_name It's not the purest "u" either (likewise with the "i"s, she holds back her vowels / doesn't push them all the way to the front of the mouth), so the mistake is understandable for a non native. To a native speaker's ears it does flow in seamlessly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb ***eu*** /y/ is very short in both cases and followed by a glide to ***un***.

I guess you confuse that ***un***, which Louane doesn't pronounce /œ̃/ but /ɛ̃/ in its un-nasalized form ***ai*** /ɛ/.

Comment: I think you're exactly right.